# Rotate a rectangle with paragraph or image as content in itext7 version 7.1.0

Tags: java, itext7

i have a rectangle that contains image  as well as text. i have to rotate that rectangle such that the image and text is rotated as well at a certain angle. Basically a replication of the same rectangle with the same content at some angle.

[image]

Comment: Your question title says you want to create a rectangle with text and your question body says that you already have such a rectangle and now want to rotate it. Please clarify.

Comment: @mkl i have changed the title.

Comment: Ah, ok, so you have as input a PDF with a rectangle and with image and text which happen to be positioned inside that rectangle. And you want to rotate the rectangle and everything inside. So first off, how can that rectangle be recognized? Is it the only rectangle on the page? Or is it at a specific location? And is it drawn using vector graphics? Is the rectangle filled? Or does it have a stroked border? Or is the rectangle itself actually a bitmap image? Are you sure the elements inside and outside the rectangle are drawn as separate entities, so their angle can be independently changed?

Comment: there is only a single spearate rectangle and image and text are filled using canvas in it. so i guess they are somehow independent. the rectangle is drawn using a specific position of x and y cordinates.

Comment: *"the rectangle is drawn using a specific position of x and y cordinates."* - ok, but what is technically drawn at that specific coordinates? Is it a bitmap image showing a rectangle? Or a vector graphics rectangle? (It would be easiest if you shared a representative example PDF.)

Comment: i have paste the image of code above.